# Creating black grunge effect on white text in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mask

I am fairly new to illustrator, have searched for the answer to this but having no luck. I am trying to add a grunge effect to white text using opacity mask and grunge textures, but it comes out grey, I would like a black effect. Can I somehow edit the opacity mask to be black, or should I be using a different technique? As far as I can tell the vectors I am using are already black. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to completely mask something using an opacity mask, the color of the object on the mask needs to be 100% C, 100% M, 100% Y, and 100% K -- or 0R, 0G, 0B. This creates a complete (registration) black that will hide all colors.

If you are finding you mask leaves behind a slight grey tint, it's because the colors on the mask are *not* full black.

---

Note I'm suggesting registration black **on the mask** only. You should really *never* use registration black on actual artwork.

Comment: Thank you! I just tried that, set color to 000000 and CMKY to 100% each and its still gray. Show black on the art board and then as soon as I release it over text, grey. Thanks for answering though, I know now how to change CMKY!

Comment: Sorry, you're going to need to post some screen shots or something. This is as far as I can *guess* without seeing something. And I didn't mean to use CMYK colors in an RGB file. If the file is RGB, you should use 0R0G0B.